# Error after ODBC configuration in MySQL

Tags: mysql, odbc, asterisk, unixodbc

I have fired this query "# echo "select 1" | isql -v asterisk-connector" got error:

> [01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib
>   '/usr/lib64/odbc/libmyodbc.so' : file not found [ISQL]ERROR: Could not
>   SQLConnect

tried to Installing and Configuring ODBC
like wise

```
sudo apt-get install unixODBC unixODBC-dev
```

This is the configuration of ODBC for MySQL in `/etc/odbcinst.ini`:

```
[MySQL]

Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

Comment: It is not clear what you tried, what failed, what you had and what you changed. Make it clear.

Comment: @fedorqui i want to connect MySql with asterisk server for the purpose i have inastalled unixODBC and unixODBC-dev. when i tried to retrieve data i got above error

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try installing:
asterisk-addons - An addons package, which includes MySQL support for call detail records

A guide how to use it:
http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MYSQL

Answer (score 1):

You need reinstall ODBC Driver and make an appropiate link to driver libraries.

Here are the full details:

https://blog.onesconsultants.com/2018/08/troubleshooting-odbc-module-in-asterisk.html